# Regex capturing simple one level hierarchy

Tags: c#, regex, preg-match

I need a regex to extract the order number and the respective order line product names Order and OrderLine anchors are constant. I managed to write a regex that captures the order and only the first order line. Can someone advise please.

Thank you.

Document example:

```
Order 123
OrderLine Some Product 1
OrderLine Some Product 2

Order 124
OrderLine Some Product 1
OrderLine Some Product 1

Some Text
```

Comment: Can you please provide the regex you already write.

Comment: C# with `preg_match`? What is the hybrid  you   are using?

Comment: Are there possible infinite `OrderLine` for one `Order`? Or are they always two?

Comment: OrderLine is infinite

Answer (score 0):

Repeat the capture of the `OrderLine` (add + or * modifier).

The [Group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group(v=vs.110).aspx) as a [Captures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures(v=vs.110).aspx) property that contains all captures matched by the capturing group.

That it, on a well formed document, the groups `productName` and `productQuantity` will have the same number of captures. You just have to iterate over it.

```
var test = @"Order 123
OrderLine Apple Tree 1
OrderLine Ananas 2

Order 124
OrderLine Tree 1
OrderLine RainBow Warrior 1";


var regEx = new Regex(@"(Order (?<orderId>\d+)(?<orderLines>\s*OrderLine\s*(?<productName>.*)\s*(?<productQuantity>\d+))+)+");

var result = regEx.Matches(test);
foreach (Match match in result)
{
    var orderId = match.Groups["orderId"];
    var productNames = match.Groups["productName"].Captures;
    var productQuantities = match.Groups["productQuantity"].Captures;

    if (productNames.Count != productQuantities.Count)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Order {orderId}");
    for (var i = 0; i < productNames.Count; i++)
    {
        var productName = productNames[i].Value;
        var productQuantity = productQuantities[i].Value;
        Console.WriteLine($"  {productQuantity} | {productName}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Order 123
  1 | Apple Tree 
  2 | Ananas 
Order 124
  1 | Tree 
  1 | RainBow Warrior
```

Sadly, I can't find a way to avoid captures length check. Use `orderLines` and iterate over it is not possible since a Group is not a match collection.